# Cómo puedo crear un nuevo data frame filtrando por una caracteristica de determinada columna?

Tags: r, dataframe

Como estan?
Lo que necesito es por ejemplo, todas las columnas que finalicen en TEXT, quitarlas y crear un nuevo df con estas columnas

[image: esta columna por ejemplo]

Comment: Si tu problema es que parte de la cabecera del archivo va a parar a los datos, puedes simplemente eliminar l primer fila `df <- df[-1, ]`

Answer (score 2):

En `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

nuevo_df<-df %>% select(ends_with("TEXT"))
```

En R base:

```
nuevo_df<-df[,grepl("TEXT$",names(df))]
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchisimas gracias